# Pass token with post request using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm new to iOS and I would like some direction on why my code isn't working. I'm trying to make a call to a url and pass a token and get the response. My response is coming back with a 404 status code.

```
let reverse = ["token": "831b21c47a7f7daee7d6e4e3fa11deaa"]

        let url =  "http://challenge.com"


        Alamofire.request(url, parameters: reverse).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which version are you using for alamofire?

Comment: version 4 @EktaMakadiya

Comment: I am assuming that your request is GET. Right?

Comment: Yes, I need to GET the response, by passing the token to that url. @EktaMakadiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bellow code:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: reverse, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once delete app from phone and run again.

Comment: I changed the method to .post and I have a response, but it's not the json response that I should be getting, and  if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }   isn't running

Comment: print(response.result) . Show me the result.

Comment: Take image of all response and share with me.

Comment: In the console the error is saying jsonSerialization failed

Comment: But are you sure your request is POST?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be - https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6d0h9xpj9puyb5/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-29%20at%202.03.19%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Well if I am suppose to post a token and get a response, then shouldn't the method be a post method?

Comment: It's not working, but I will take a look in the am and check a few other things

Comment: Okay. Let me know its working or not. I have other solutions also.

Comment: Okay I will! Thanks

Comment: When I pass the token as a param, with a post method using postman I get a 200 status code. But I'm not sure how to go about it with Alamofire.

Comment: I got it to work, the issue was I was using .responseJSON and it was suppose to be .responseString

Comment: @D'AndreEaly Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

This code is also handle the error when response will be the blank and also the Internet connection is disable.

```
func apiCall(params : [String:AnyObject],block:([String:AnyObject]->Void)?) {

     if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON{
            response in

            let data = response.result.value
            if data == nil{
                if response.result.error?.code == -1005 {
                        print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            else{
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    block!(data as! [String:AnyObject])
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
          }
        }
        else{
            print(NO_NETWORK)
        } 
  }
```